# How to zip and unzip folders and its sub folders in Silverlight?

Tags: zip, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I have a Windows Phone application. I am using SharpZipLib to zip folders and its sub folders. This is zipping only the folder but the data inside the folders is not getting zipped. Can anyone guide me how to do this?

My code:

```
private void btnZip_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile appStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            foreach (string filename in appStore.GetFileNames(directoryName + "/" + "*.txt"))
            {                   
               GetCompressedByteArray(filename);
            }
            textBlock2.Text = "Created file has Zipped Successfully";
        }
    }
 public byte[] GetCompressedByteArray(string content)
        {
            byte[] compressedResult;
            using (MemoryStream zippedMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(zippedMemoryStream))
                {
                    zipOutputStream.SetLevel(9);
                    byte[] buffer;                   
                    using (MemoryStream file = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)))
                    {
                        buffer = new byte[file.Length];
                        file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    }                    
                    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(content);
                    zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(entry);
                    zipOutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    zipOutputStream.Finish();
                }
                compressedResult = zippedMemoryStream.ToArray();
            }
            WriteToIsolatedStorage(compressedResult);
            return compressedResult;
        }

        public void WriteToIsolatedStorage(byte[] compressedBytes)
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile appStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            appStore.CreateDirectory(ZipFolder);
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream zipTemplateStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(ZipFolder+"/"+directoryName + ".zip", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, appStore))
            using (BinaryWriter streamWriter = new BinaryWriter(zipTemplateStream))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(compressedBytes);
            }
        }
```

Comment: There is another library: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/ . Eventually it works with this library?

Comment: Is it not possible with SharpZipLib ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find [this guide](http://devpinoy.org/blogs/keithrull/archive/2008/01/25/how-to-create-zip-files-in-c-with-sharpziplib-ziplib.aspx) helpful.

An excerpt from the above link

> The ZipFile object provides a method called AddDirectory() that
> accepts a parameter directoryName. The problem with this method is
> that it doesn't add the files inside the specified directory but
> instead just creates a directory inside the zip file. To make this
> work, you need to get the files inside that directory by looping thru
> all objects in that directory and adding them one at a time. I was
> able to accomplish this task by creating a recursive function that
> drills through the whole directory structure of the folder you want to
> zip. Below is a snippet of the function.

I guess you too are facing the same problem where the folder is added to the zip file, but the contents and sub folders are not zipped.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919494/how-to-zip-and-unzip-root-folder-in-isolated-storage-containing-subfolders-and-f) for a code sample on how to use SharpZipLib to zip a root folder including nested folders.